# Не работает df.rolling...опять

Tags: python

Неделю назад у меня все работало,
сегодня перезапускаю Colab и не работает

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[1, 20, 1], [2, 22, 1], [3, 23, 0], [1, 19, 1], [2, 24, 0],
                 [2, 21, 1], [1, 17, 1], [2, 29, 0], [2, 27, 0]],
                 columns=['type', 'size', 'target'])
a['size2'] = a['size'].rolling(window=(7,10), min_periods=1, win_type='exponential').mean(std=0.1)
```

### ValueError: exponential window requires tau

С win_type='gaussian' работает

Comment: я запустил, все работает

Comment: Не работает в Colab

Comment: @svil, какаю у вас версия Pandas?

Comment: версия Pandas 1.0.3